# Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.String,MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel+MyClassData]' to type 'MyClassData'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am having an issue with grouping in my ASP.NET MVC4 (Razor View Engine) VS 2012 project.  I am using Entity Framework.  My code is below:

Thanks for any help.

I am getting the error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.String,MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel+MyClassData]' to type 'MyClassData'.
```

MYCLASS

```
    public class MyClassData
    {
       public int? Id { get; set; }
       public int? ParentId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }   
    }

    private readonly List<MyClassData> mData = new List<MyClassData>();


    public List<MyClassData> SpecData
    {
      get { return mData; }
    }


    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassData>>
    query = (from t in db.MydbProcedure(temp)
                       select new MyClassData
                       {
                          Id = t.Id,
                          ParentId = t.ParentId,
                          Title = t.Title
                       }).OrderBy(x =>x.Id).GroupBy(y => y.Title);

  List<IGrouping<string, MyClassData>> mSpec = query.ToList();

            mData .Clear();
            mSpec.ForEach(b =>
            {
                if (b != null)
                    mData.Add((MyClassData)b);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mSpec.ForEach(b =>
            {
                if (b != null)
                    mData.AddRange(b);
            });
```

edit:
for more content and quality! YAY!

the problem in your code is: `b` is no instance of `MyClassData` ... b is an IGrouping< K,V> and also an IEnumerable< V> ... since V is `MyClassData` in this case, you can add to mData using the AddRange(IEnumerable< V> obj) Method

in simple words ... you tried to use a collection of `MyClassData` as a single instance of `MyClassData` ...

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Perhaps more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I can't check your code but I think this code will help you:

```
List<IGrouping<string, MyClassData>> query = new List<MyClassData>()
    .GroupBy(it => it.Title)
    .ToList();

List<MyClassData> mData = query
    .Where(b => b != null)
    .SelectMany(it => it)
    .ToList();
```

You can simply add `Where` and `SelectMany` clauses to your query in order to get the same result.

I'm not sure if `Where` clause is really needed in your code.

I think you can write even the following:

```
List<MyClassData> mData = (from t in db.MydbProcedure(temp)
                            select new MyClassData
                            {
                                Id = t.Id,
                                ParentId = t.ParentId,
                                Title = t.Title
                            })
    .OrderBy(it => it.Id)
    .GroupBy(it => it.Title)
    .Where(b => b != null)
    .SelectMany(it => it)
    .ToList();
```